# VBA - Creating Incremental Unique IDs based on Conditionals

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, uniqueidentifier, unique-id

File: https://file.io/wxugbESk

I am trying to create dynamic incremental IDs that are created off the values within tab "A"-- conditionally adding up the values based off of columns "B:D"'s values. These are non-sequential, but unique to the last maximum value within its conditional population.

**Logical Formula:**
ID = Conditional Value Maximum + 1

So if the ID does not exist yet, it will begin with '001', i.e. "111001".

There is no limit to the amount of IDs created and the loop I have tried does not work, nor do I think a loop is necessary.

For Example:

[image]

I keep retrieving the same value as I have within the list, but the value should increase by the value of 1 if the value already exists.

I have been rolling over left-and-right to get this to work with no luck. If you need me to elaborate any further I will do so. I would post my code, but I do not believe it will be any help.

```
=IF(ISERROR(IF($B3=VLOOKUP($B3,'Position ID detail'!$C$8:$C$15,1,FALSE),INDEX('Position ID detail'!$B$8:$C$15,MATCH($B3,'Position ID detail'!$C$8:$C$15,0),1),"----")+IF($C3=VLOOKUP($C3,'Position ID detail'!$F$8:$F$17,1,FALSE),INDEX('Position ID detail'!$E$8:$F$17,MATCH($C3,'Position ID detail'!$F$8:$F$17,0),1),"----")+IF($D3=VLOOKUP($D3,'Position ID detail'!$I$8:$I$11,1,FALSE),INDEX('Position ID detail'!$H$8:$I$11,MATCH($D3,'Position ID detail'!$I$8:$I$11,0),1))+1=VLOOKUP(IF($B3=VLOOKUP($B3,'Position ID detail'!$C$8:$C$15,1,FALSE),INDEX('Position ID detail'!$B$8:$C$15,MATCH($B3,'Position ID detail'!$C$8:$C$15,0),1),"----")+IF($C3=VLOOKUP($C3,'Position ID detail'!$F$8:$F$17,1,FALSE),INDEX('Position ID detail'!$E$8:$F$17,MATCH($C3,'Position ID detail'!$F$8:$F$17,0),1),"----")+IF($D3=VLOOKUP($D3,'Position ID detail'!$I$8:$I$11,1,FALSE),INDEX('Position ID detail'!$H$8:$I$11,MATCH($D3,'Position ID detail'!$I$8:$I$11,0),1))+1,A$2:A2,1,FALSE)),IF($B3=VLOOKUP($B3,'Position ID detail'!$C$8:$C$15,1,FALSE),INDEX('Position ID detail'!$B$8:$C$15,MATCH($B3,'Position ID detail'!$C$8:$C$15,0),1),"----")+IF($C3=VLOOKUP($C3,'Position ID detail'!$F$8:$F$17,1,FALSE),INDEX('Position ID detail'!$E$8:$F$17,MATCH($C3,'Position ID detail'!$F$8:$F$17,0),1),"----")+IF($D3=VLOOKUP($D3,'Position ID detail'!$I$8:$I$11,1,FALSE),INDEX('Position ID detail'!$H$8:$I$11,MATCH($D3,'Position ID detail'!$I$8:$I$11,0),1))+1,MAXIFS(A$2:A2,B$2:B2,B3,C$2:C2,C3,D$2:D2,D3)+1)
```

Comment: `MAXIFS` should be helpful.

Comment: @BigBen Would it though? As the only range I am using as my basis is "A$2:A3" within the ID column. MAXIFS requires two arrays, the max range and criteria range.

Comment: It looks like columns B through D are your criteria... *based off of columns "B:D"'s values.*

Comment: Maybe I did not phrase my problem correctly. I can create my unique ID, but I cannot calculate the next ID that contains the same conditionals. Maybe I have been just staring at this for so long that something is not clicking. 
I have included what I wrote as just a function as I am trying to break it down to the simplest of formats currently. All it does is identify that the ID already exists within the column array.

Comment: maybe use the hashing functionality of a collection as a lookuptable. first store all ids that hve to be unique already, then with every new item check if the id is already contained, if so just increase the id with 1 and check again

Comment: @BigBen YOU ROCK -- I needed to walk around the room for a second, but I will update the function in the code box. Forgot about the functionality of MAXIFS. Not sure why I started out trying to code this. Kudos my friend.